# Equivalent characterizations of the essential image of reflective subcategories

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I'm currently trying to prove the third item of the following exercise from [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf),

> **Exercise 4.5.vii.** Consider a reflective subcategory inclusion $D \hookrightarrow C$ with reflector $L: C \to D$.
>
> 1. Show that $\eta L = L\eta$, and that these natural transformations are isomorphisms.
> 2. Show that an object $c \in C$ is in the essential image of the inclusion $D\hookrightarrow C$, meaning that it is isomorphic to an object in the subcategory $D$, if and only if $\eta_c$ is an isomorphism.
> 3. Show that the essential image of $D$ consists of those objects $c$ that are local for the class of morphisms that are inverted by $L$. That is, $c$ is in the essential image if and only if the pre-composition functions
>      $$
>    C(b, c) \xrightarrow{f^*} C(a, c)
>    $$
>      are isomorphisms for all maps $f : a \to b$ in $C$ for which $Lf$ is an isomorphism in $D$. This explains why the reflector is also referred to as “localization.”

Here $\eta$ is the unit of the adjunction. I have managed to prove the first two items. However, reflective subcategories were just briefly introduced and so I am not sure how to relate item $(3)$ with $(2)$, if this is the right path to begin with. Any hints? I would also appreciate if someone can shed some light on the term *localization* and why $(3)$ 'explains' this nomenclature.

Comment: (Part 1 was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4494089/394668).)

Comment: For the record, here's one way of seeing part 2: Denote $I:D\to C$ to the inclusion and suppose there's an isomorphism $f^\flat:c\cong Id$. Then $f^\sharp:Lc\xrightarrow{Lf^\flat}LId\xrightarrow{\varepsilon_d}d$ is a composite of isos, hence, and iso. Since $f^\flat:c\xrightarrow{\eta_c}ILc\xrightarrow{If^\sharp}Id$ is an iso, $\eta_c$ must be an iso as well.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in part 2 one can add "and iff $\eta_c$ is a split epi." Indeed, suppose $f\cdot \eta_c=1_c$, for some $f:Lc\to c$. Then, using naturality of $\eta$ first and relation $L\eta=\eta L$ after \[[ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4494089/394668)], we get
$\eta_c\cdot f=Lf\cdot\eta_{Lc}=Lf\cdot L\eta_c=L(f\cdot \eta_c)=L1_c=1_{Lc}$. Thus, $\eta_c$ is invertible and $f=\eta_c^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: First prove that $iLc$ satisfies the condition in 3, where $i:D\to C$ is the inclusion. Then use apply 2 to conclude.

Regarding "localization" the point is that $L$ is characterized by the arrows it inverts, so the language is being imported from commutative algebra. Specifically, the motivating situation is that of $R[S^{-1}]$-modules, where $S$ is a multiplicative set in a commutative ring $R$. Every $R[S^{-1}]$ is functorially an $R$-module by restricting the scalars, and this functor is fully faithful, with the left adjoint $R[S^{-1}]\otimes_R (-)$. So this is a reflective subcategory. Furthermore an $R$-module admits an $R[S^{-1}]$-action if and only if it is local for those $R$-module maps inverted by tensoring with $R[S^{-1}]$, as in Riehl's point 3. The classical algebraic framework would reduce those maps to the maps $s:R\to R$ determined by elements of $S$, while the general categorical framework instead asks for locality with respect to all maps $\eta_A:A\to A[S^{-1}]$, for $A$ an $R$-module. We can bridge these frameworks by observing that locality with respect to each $s$ is equivalent to locality with respect to the single unit map $R\to R[S^{-1}]$, which implies locality with respect to every $\eta_A$ by considering the action of $L$ on a presentation of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I've got your hint, but still can't manage to finish this off. If $c$ is on the essential  image via $w : c \simeq Ld$, then $Ld$ verifies the condition in $(3)$ and thus so does $c$ via factoring $f^*$ through $f^* : C(b,Ld) \to C(a,Ld), w_* : C(a,c) \to C(a,Ld), w_* : C(b,c) \to C(b,Ld)$.

Comment: (cont.) However the converse is still unclear to me: if $c$ verifies the condition on $(3)$, we can apply this to $\eta_c$ (as $(1)$ guarantees that $L\eta_c$ is an iso). I see how this shows that $\eta_c$ is a split epi: if $a$ is the inverse of $\eta_c^*$, then $a(1_c)\eta_c =( \eta_c^* a)(1_c) = 1_c$.  However, can we assert that this arrow is actually an iso? Having $Lc \simeq c$ for any $c$ in the essential image seems too strong, but I may have bad intuition on this.

Comment: @GuidoA. Actually, $Lc$ is indeed isomorphic to $c$ in that case. Given an iso $a:c\to Lc'$, we have a naturality square involving $a,La, $ and $\eta_{Lc'}$, all of which are iso, as well as $\eta_c$. So the latter is an iso as well.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments, I feel like that this addendum to @Kevin Arlin's answer may be useful.

Here's a proof for one direction of the third item.

Consider $\eta_c : c \to iLc$; by the first item $iL\eta_c : iLc \to iLc$ is iso so that $\eta^{*}_c: \mathsf{C}(iLc,c) \to \mathsf{C}(c,c)$ is a bijection.
In particular there is a unique $s: iLc \to c$ such that $s \eta_c = 1_c$.
This implies that $iLs \cdot iL\eta_c = 1_{iLc}$; now, $iL\eta_c=\eta_{iLc}$ is an isomorphism, and by the triangular identities, its inverse is $i\epsilon_{Lc}$.
Therefore $iLs=i\epsilon_{Lc}$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \eta_c s= iLs \cdot \eta_{iLc} = i\epsilon_{Lc} \cdot \eta_{iLc} = 1_{iLc}
\end{equation*}
where the first equality follows from naturality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof of part 3. Denote $I:\mathsf{D}\to \mathsf{C}$ to the inclusion.

$(\Rightarrow)$. Let $f:a\to b\in\mathsf{C}$ be such that $Lf$ is an iso. It suffices to show that $\mathsf{C}(b,Id)\xrightarrow{f^*}\mathsf{C}(a,Id)$ is an iso. We have a naturality commutative square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathsf{C}(b,Id)@>{f^*}>>\mathsf{C}(a,Id)\\
@V{\cong}VV@VV{\cong}V\\
\mathsf{D}(Lb,d)@>{\smash{Lf^*}}>>\mathsf{D}(La,d)
\end{CD}
$$
Since three out of four arrows is an iso, so is the fourth one.

$(\Leftarrow)$. By part 1, $L\eta_{c'}$ is an iso for all $c'\in\mathsf{C}$. Hence, by hypothesis, $\mathsf{C}(ILc,c)\xrightarrow{\eta_c^*}\mathsf{C}(c,c)$ is bijective, so there is $f:ILc\to c$ with $f\cdot\eta_c=1_c$. By $(\Rightarrow)$, the map $\mathsf{C}(ILc,ILc)\xrightarrow{\eta_c^*}\mathsf{C}(c,ILc)$ is a bijection. But this last map sends both $\eta_c\cdot f$ and $1_{ILc}$ to the same morphism, whence $\eta_c\cdot f=1_{ILc}$.